# Run and rank all combination of features to machine learning model

Tags: python, for-loop, machine-learning, feature-selection

I have a train and test data set which contains 30 independent features and 1 target feature.

All the features are numerical variables. An example of the train data set looks like. The test data set also has the same columns

| Target | col1 | col2 | ... | col29 | col30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 12 | 14 | ... | 15 | 12 |
| 25 | 13 | 25 | ... | 19 | 19 |

I want to write an efficient code to run all combination of the features to a light GBM regressor model on test data set to find out the best combination of features which gave the best MAE.

An example of the result output that I am looking for should look like this

| Rank | Features_used | MAE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | col1,col2,col14,col17,col18 | 2.40 |
| 2 | col4,col5,col15,col19,col24 | 2.50 |
| 3 | col4,col5,col15,col19,col24,col29,col18,col13 | 2.50 |
| -- | ---- | --- |
| -- | ---- | --- |
| -- | ---- | --- |
| -- | ---- | --- |
| n | worst combination of features | Worst MAE |

I have tried passing each combination of features individually and finding out the MAE but it seems inefficient while trying out all the combinations.

```
Predict = 'Target'
train = train[['Target','col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']]
test = test[['Target','col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']]
X_train = train[train.columns.difference([Predict])]
X_test =  test[test.columns.difference([Predict])]
y_train = train[Predict]
y_test = test[Predict]
regressor = lightgbm.LGBMRegressor()
regressor= regressor.fit(X_train, y_train,eval_metric = ["MAE"])
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

Is there an efficient way to run all the combination of features and rank the output based on the MAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The first step is the do every combination of the features with keeping the "target" within every combination.
- The second step is to iterate over every combination, train, predict and calculate the MAE and store it in a dataframe among the features used
- The final one, is to sort the dataframe based on the MAE.

  ```
    from itertools import compress, product
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error as mae
    #This fonctions will be used to have every combinations of features for the model
    def combinations(items):
        return ( list(set(compress(items,mask))) for mask in product(*[[0,1]]*len(items)) )

    def lgbm(train, test, all_columns):
        Predict = 'Target'
        train = train[all_columns]
        test = test[all_columns]
        X_train = train[train.columns.difference([Predict])]
        X_test =  test[test.columns.difference([Predict])]
        y_train = train[Predict]
        y_test = test[Predict]
        regressor = lightgbm.LGBMRegressor()
        regressor= regressor.fit(X_train, y_train,eval_metric = ["MAE"])
        y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
        #Calculate the MAE
        mae_error = mae(y_test, y_pred)
        return mae_error

    d = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Features_used","MAE"])

    all_columns = ['Target','col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']
    #Iterate over every combinations of features and train the model,
    #get the MAE and append it with the features used in the dataframe
    combi_col = list(combinations(np.arange(start=1, stop=len(all_columns))))[1:] #starting from index 1 to drop empty list
    for columns in combi_col:
        columns = [all_columns[i] for i in columns+[0]] 
        #index 0 referes to the target columns because it must be always included in every combination
        error = lgbm(train,test, columns)
        d = d.append({"Features_used":",".join(columns),"MAE":error},ignore_index=True)
    d['Rank'] = d['MAE'].rank(ascending = 0).astype(int)
    d = d.sort_values(["MAE"],ascending=False)
    d = d[["Rank","Features_used","MAE"]]
    d
  ```

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply, I get an error "combinations() missing 1 required positional argument: 'items'" . Am i supposed to add all_columns as an argument to combi_col?

Comment: The above worked

Comment: I forget to add the paramter of combinations, try it now and tell me